# Selector requires drawable attribute?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ff0000"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#0000ff"/>
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

I have this selector which I'm trying to use to change the background of a Linearlayout.  Whenever I try to apply it, however I always get this error message:

*org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable*

Obviously, it want me to use the drawable attibute but I'm not sure how to do that and change the background like I want to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
android:drawable="@color/red"
```

and add this in  every item with diffrent color....

Comment: anyone know why this is required, when the docs show that specifying color directly should work? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html Is it due to targeting an old SDK?

Comment: @Linus, using `android:color` will work (and must be included) if you are specifying a color property (i.e., using your selector like `android:textColor="@color/..."`). If you are specifying a drawable property (i.e., `android:background="@..."`), it looks for an `android:drawable` attribute.

Comment: @karl yes indeed the link I posted is to a color (state list) resource, not a drawable, which `android:background` requires! probably skimmed the docs again too quickly back then. :)